# SQL BigQuery call the column with multiple dots in the name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have column named something like `name.subname.subsubname` from database which is called `database`.

How can I access it? I tried `[name.subname.subsubname]` and `[name].[subname].[subsubname]` and `name.subname.subsubname` with ` - nothing worked.

I'm using SQL BigQuery.

Comment: This would normally refer to a nested record.  You can just use `name.subname.subsubname`.

Comment: any error thrown it?

Comment: If just run it without anying like ` or [ the error is Cannot access field adjustment on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<adjustment STRUCT<tax_in_cents INT64, origin STRING, end_date TIMESTAMP, ...>>>

Comment: name.subname.subsubname is this your column name or  "name" is database name "subname" is table name and "subsubname" is column name?

Comment: name.subname.subname - all the column name. Database and table are called differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't add enough context to the question, but from the error in the comment I think this would work

```
SELECT name[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].subname.subsubname
```

This because the error `Cannot access field adjustment on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<adjustment STRUCT<tax_in_cents INT64` shows that you are working with an array, and before navigating an array with `.`, you need to get individual elements from it - which you can do with `[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]` to get the first one.